# Android - Calling GONE and then VISIBLE makes the view to be shown in the wrong place

Tags: android, user-interface, view, visibility

I have two views, A and B, and the view A is above the view B (both are linear layouts).

When I, programmatically, set the view A to be GONE, it disappears and the view that was right below it (B) goes to the place of the view A (as expected).

However, when I set the very same view (A) to VISIBLE again, it is being shown OVER the view B. I don't want that. I want the view B to go back to its original position (below the view A) which is what I thought it would happen (but it doesn't). How can I do that?

Thank you in advance!

### EDIT - Code

```
package com.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.ScaleAnimation;
import android.view.animation.Transformation;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;

public class ViewGoneEffectActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private View viewComEfeito = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    findViewById(R.id.outroLinear).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.segundo).setOnClickListener(this);

    viewComEfeito = findViewById(R.id.outroLinear);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    if (view.getId() == R.id.outroLinear) {

        view.startAnimation(new MyScaler(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 500, view,
                true));


    }else if(view.getId() == R.id.segundo){
        viewComEfeito.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

public class MyScaler extends ScaleAnimation {

    private LayoutParams mLayoutParams;

    private int mMarginBottomFromY, mMarginBottomToY;

    private boolean mVanishAfter = false;

    public MyScaler(float fromX, float toX, float fromY, float toY,
            int duration, View view, boolean vanishAfter) {

        super(fromX, toX, fromY, toY);
        setDuration(duration);
        mVanishAfter = vanishAfter;
        mLayoutParams = (LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();

        //int height = mView.getHeight();
        int height = viewComEfeito.getHeight();
        mMarginBottomFromY = (int) (height * fromY) + mLayoutParams.bottomMargin - height;
        mMarginBottomToY = (int) (0 - ((height * toY) + mLayoutParams.bottomMargin)) - height;
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime,
            Transformation t) {

        super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);

        if (interpolatedTime < 1.0f) {
            int newMarginBottom = mMarginBottomFromY + (int) ((mMarginBottomToY - mMarginBottomFromY) * interpolatedTime);
            mLayoutParams.setMargins(mLayoutParams.leftMargin,  mLayoutParams.topMargin, mLayoutParams.rightMargin, newMarginBottom);
            viewComEfeito.getParent().requestLayout();

        } else if (mVanishAfter) {
            viewComEfeito.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

}

And here goes the XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/outroLinear"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Welcome to the real world" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No" />

                <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Wow! =P" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Free your mind!" />

                <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="In Tylor we trust" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="First rule of fight club is" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:id="@+id/segundo" />


 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please add some code stuff to let us know your problem...

Comment: I edited my question with the code. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

you could try putting both views inside a RelativeLayout and set their position relative to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting both the layout A and B in another Linear Layout say C which has following property:-  height wrap_content  , Orientation Vertical It will work as you want :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to call measure(width,height) after the view changed to be visible. 
Otherwise view will be displayed differently.